# How to prevent WKWebView from being emptied after app sent to background

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, webkit, wkwebview

I am developing an app that uses `WKWebView` to render web content.
Everything works fine so far except one thing: if I load a page on my `WKWebView` then send the app to the background for a while (I'd say around ten minutes) and reopen the app, my `WKWebView` is empty.

I guess it is automatically emptied to prevent memory waste, but then what do Safari or Chrome do in order to keep the web page content in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

My guess is that your app is actually getting terminated while it is suspended, and you are getting re-launched. You can't prevent that either.

If the system needs memory it will send your app a low memory app delegate message and notification. The WKWebView may subscribe to that notification and clear the page if it gets a low memory notification.

Comment: But then how do Google and Apple do with their respective browsers ? Do you think they cache the content of every web page ( in `NSUserDefaults` for instance ) whenever the app turns inactive ?

Comment: No, I think they cache the URLs of each page and then re-load it when you select a tab.